# C Fibonacci Sequence in Array Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, fibonacci

I want to fill an array up to n digits of the Fibonacci sequence. Here's what I have so far:

```
void fib(int **seq, int n){
    seq = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    if(n==1){
        *seq[0] = 0;
    }

    if(n==2){
        *seq[0] = 0;
        *seq[1] = 1;
    }

    if(n>=3){
        *seq[0] = 0;
        *seq[1] = 1;
        *seq[2] = 1;
        for(int i=3; i<n; i++){
            *seq[i] = *seq[i-1]+*seq[i-2];
        }

    }
}
```

I've tested the basic algorithm in Python and it works as expected, but in C I'm getting a segmentation fault and I'm not sure where that is coming from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Probably, `seq = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);` --> `*seq = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`, `*seq[0] = 0;` --> `(*seq)[0] = 0;` (`(*seq)[1] = 1;` ...)

Comment: What is `seq[0]`? As well as `seq[1]` etc. Those are pointers to memory. Are they initialized? No. Can you dereference them safely?

Comment: No, I'm relatively new to C and the command line

Comment: You should _definitely_ learn how to use a debugger. Also, a GUI debugger is going to be much, much easier for a newcomer to learn - command line debuggers are typically much more hard to use for beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is correct on most parts except for the following errors:

(1) Repalce

`seq = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`

with

`*seq = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`

Note that you should not be allocating memory to the double pointer.  You should be allocating the memory to the pointer pointed by 'seq'.

(2) Replace all the statements like

`*seq[i]...`

with

`(*seq)[i]`

Note that [] has a stronger affinity than *. So you need to surround *seq with parenthesis on all the instances.

(3) You haven't shown how you invoke this function. But I am assuming that you are allocating memory to the double pointer before calling the function.

Here's a working program for your reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fib(int **seq, int n);

int main()
{
    int ** sequence = malloc(sizeof(int*));       

    fib(sequence, 5);
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
       printf("%d", (*sequence)[x]);
    return 0;
}

void fib(int **seq, int n){
    *seq = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    if(n==1){
        (*seq)[0] = 0;
    }

    if(n==2){
        (*seq)[0] = 0;
        (*seq)[1] = 1;
    }

    if(n>=3){
        (*seq)[0] = 0;
        (*seq)[1] = 1;
        (*seq)[2] = 1;
        for(int i=3; i<n; i++){
            (*seq)[i] = (*seq)[i-1]+(*seq)[i-2];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: check my answer I hope you will find this useful

Comment: I want to call the function from main as: `int *fib_sequence; fib(&fib_sequence, 5);`

Comment: Sure. In that case, you still need to allocate memory to fib_sequence like `int * fib_sequence = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);`. And then while reading the values after the function call, you can do `for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
   printf("%d", fib_sequence[x]);`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `pointer of pointer` that is `void fib(int **seq, int n)`
than try to allocate memory `seq = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);` which is wrong

Instead of doing this you can simply do

```
void fib(int *seq, int n){



if(n==1){

    seq[0] = 0;
}

if(n==2){
    seq[0] = 0;
    seq[1] = 1;
}

if(n>=3){
    seq[0] = 0;
    seq[1] = 1;
    seq[2] = 1;
    for(int i=3; i<n; i++){

        seq[i] = seq[i-1]+seq[i-2];
    }

}
}
int main()
{

int n=10;
int *arr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n)); // Allocate memory here 
fib(arr,10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand this :
for arrays:-

```
a[i] = *(a+i) // correct
```

so

```
*a[i] = **(a+i) //pointer to pointer so it will not work in your case
```